# loading java string into localstorage

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I hava a String `"hi ima string!"` stored in the string variable `myString` in a java class. I have a method `getMyString()` I want to be able to load `myString` into localStorage on my jsp page and then display from localStorage. Also I would want to do some string manipulation before or after.

1. how do I save a java class variable to localStorage?
2. how do I do string manipulation with an item in localStorage?
3. how do I display the item in localStorage on the page?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think OP gets that

Comment: Sorry, what is the question then? [Local Storage and How to Use it](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
// stores the java value
localStorage['someKey'] = "<%= myJavaVar %>";

// do manipulations
var s2 = "value:" + localStorage['someKey'];

// very cheap display
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s2));  
</script>
```

Comment: Not very safe however. Isin't there any native Java util to make a string JSsafe?

Comment: You could use a JSON encoder, for example gson. Personally I do all exchanges java-js in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var myString = "<%= obj.getMyString() %>";
localStorage.setItem("myString", myString);   //Saves to localStorage

To retrieve it from local storage (may be in other script or page in the same domain):

var myString = localStorage.setItem("myString");
alert(myString);   //Shows it
```

Hope this helps. 
Cheers.